# Assigning a sum to a variable gives a KeyError in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x

I am trying to sum a column of a dataframe:

`print x['count: revenue_sale'].sum()` does not give an error, and gives the correct output.

When I try `y = x['count: revenue_sale'].sum()` I get `KeyError: 'count: revenue_sale'`

```
def dfCreator(x):

    dcs = [col for col in x.columns if col.startswith("dc")]
    groups = x.groupby(dcs)["uid"].unique()

    groups = list(x.groupby(dcs, as_index=False))
    summed = [i[1].sum() for i in groups]

    x = pd.DataFrame(summed)

    x['interaction_eis_rate'] = x['count: interaction_eis'] / x['dc(uid): interaction_eis']
    x['interaction_eis_reply_rate'] = x['count: interaction_eis_reply'] / x['dc(uid): interaction_eis_reply']
    x['interaction_interaction_match_rate'] = x['count: interaction_match'] / x['dc(uid): interaction_match']
    x['interaction_single_message__rate'] = x['count: interaction_single_message_'] / x['dc(uid): interaction_single_message_']
    x['interaction_single_message_1_rate'] = x['count: interaction_single_message_1'] / x['dc(uid): interaction_single_message_1']
    x['interaction_yes_rate'] = x['count: interaction_yes'] / x['dc(uid): interaction_yes']


    x = x.drop(x.columns[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]], axis=1)

    print(x.columns)

    y = x['count: revenue_sale'].sum()

    return x

pre_purch_m = dfCreator(pre_purch_m) 
pre_purch_f = dfCreator(pre_purch_f)
all_m_rm = dfCreator(all_m_rm) 
all_f_rm = dfCreator(all_f_rm)
```

The output of print(x.colums) is

```
Index([u'count: revenue_sale', u'interaction_eis_rate', u'interaction_eis_reply_rate', u'interaction_interaction_match_rate', u'interaction_single_message__rate', u'interaction_single_message_1_rate', u'interaction_yes_rate'], dtype='object')
6045

Index([u'count: revenue_sale', u'interaction_eis_rate', u'interaction_eis_reply_rate', u'interaction_interaction_match_rate', u'interaction_single_message__rate', u'interaction_single_message_1_rate', u'interaction_yes_rate'], dtype='object')
1082

Index([u'dc(uid): interaction_eis', u'interaction_interaction_match_rate', u'interaction_single_message__rate', u'interaction_single_message_1_rate', u'interaction_yes_rate'], dtype='object')
```

I assume it is breaking on the third function call?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well it's impossible for anyone to reproduce this unless you provide data and code, the error shouldn't happen but as I don't have your PC in front of me I can't tell you why this can happen

Comment: If you want to convince me this is really going on, you need to add `print(x.columns)` *immediately before* the `y = x['count: revenue_sale'].sum()` line.  :-)  It's a lot more likely that you're wrong that it's still there.  [PS: if you're not using the grouped ids for anything, there's no need for the first `groups` line.  You're finding them and then immediately reassigning `groups` to something else.]

Comment: @DSM i edited it and think i found the issue, it is breaking on the third function call which doesnt seem to have that column

Comment: Well it's highly likely it doesn't exist in `all_m_rm`